# C++ spaceship operator `default` marked as deleted with `std::array` member

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

I am trying to understand why the spaceship operator for an `std::array` is marked as `deleted` when the `std::array` is a member, while the `operator<=>` itself is defined for `std::array`. I am using Apple Clang (XCode 14.1).

The following code does not compile

```
#include <array>
#include <compare>

struct test
{
    std::array<std::int64_t, 1> coords;
    auto operator<=>(const test&) const = default;
};

void test_f() {
    test c1{1}, c2{2};
    auto t1 = (c1 <= c2);
}
```

the error being

```
defaulted 'operator<=>' is implicitly deleted because there is no viable 
three-way comparison function for member 'coords'
```

However the code here compiles without issue:

```
void test_2() {
    std::array<std::int64_t, 1> coords{0};
    auto t1 = (coords <= coords);
}
```

and I was expecting the `operator<=>` for the `struct test` uses the definition of `operator<=>` for `std::array` when applied to this little struct.

## clang versions (edit)

```bash
 % which clang
/usr/bin/clang

 % clang --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

and tried also with

```bash
 % clang --version
clang version 15.0.2                                                             
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0                                                 
Thread model: posix                                                              
InstalledDir: /Volumes/Data/program/clang+llvm-15.0.2-arm64-apple-darwin21.0/bin
```

on macOS m1.

### Compilation (edit)

The steps for reproducing are like this:

1. download an official `clang` build and deflate the archive
2. pull `clang` to `PATH`

   ```bash
   export PATH=/Volumes/Data/programs/clang+llvm-15.0.3-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. make sure `clang` is trusted (open the folder containing `clang` w. Finder, right click, select open, and execute)
4. run the following command line

   ```bash
   export SDKROOT=$(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx)
   clang --version
   clang -std=c++20 -isysroot $SDKROOT/ test.cpp
   ```

   where `test.cpp` is the snippet above.

I have 100% error reproducibility with this and tested 2 different Xcode, 2 different architectures, and clang 14.0.0, 15.0.0, 15.0.1 and 15.0.3.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's working for me [here](https://godbolt.org/z/eMv4Kv1ar). What's the compiler line you are using?

Comment: Sounds like a compiler/library bug.

Comment: I am a bit lost: it works on godbolt.org but I tried on a macOS m1/clang 15.0.1/XCode 14.1+Xcode13.1 (arm) and macOS x86_64/clang 14.0.0, 15.0.1, 15.0.3 (intel) and I always have the same error. I am editing the question to indicate the compilation line.

Comment: Apple's c++ [compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) is horribly out of date and should never be used. They've yet to fully implement even c++ 17 features. I wouldn't expect them to have finished implementing c++20 features until 2030.

Comment: @Casey I am downloading the official `clang` from project website. Does not work.

Comment: Created a question on [clang discourse](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/c-spaceship-operator-default-marked-as-deleted-with-std-array-member/66529)